# Invalid Data Source PHP PDO Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
#require_once('inc/dbc1.php');
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=somehost;
$user = 'someuser';
$password = 'SomePass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$pdo1 = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$pdo1->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth1 = $pdo1->prepare('SELECT pID, lname, fname FROM Professor ORDER BY pID DESC LIMIT 5;');
$sth1->execute(array());
?>
```

Throws the error:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name' in  PDO->__construct('', NULL, NULL) on line 1
```

Anyone see anything wrong with this?

Comment: In my opinion, this issue must be caused by your setting string, please double check your settings. Perhaps caused by your dsn string, how about add the port 3306 by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=somehost;
```

maybe just maybe ...

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=somehost';
```

unless this was a mouso when cut-and-pasting the question.

Comment: good spotted! But really this should be spotted by the IDE used by JohnPaul.